# Jquery DataTable fnServerData Error

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, web-services, datatable

I am attempting to load my jQuery Datatable via Ajax from an asp.net web server (.asmx) file.

I am using the following jQuery:

```
            $("#taskTable").dataTable({
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "ajaxPages/getTheTasks.asmx/getAllTasks",
            "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                alert("test");
                aoData.push({ "name": "id", "value": ProjectID });
                $.getJSON(sSource, aoData, function (json) {
                    fnCallback(json);
                });
            }
        });
```

I have been debugging with firebug.  I can stop on each of the lines all the way down to "fnserverData".  Once I hit that line, I can't step into the function.  The alert never triggers.  I never even get to send a request to the web service.  It just skips over.  I've rewritten this code several times and based it off of several different examples.

This code here is nearly verbatim from the datatables websites, which does work. (The datatables website example uses a PHP source.  I even copied that source and tried to use that through the sAjaxSource but it still didn't step into the fnServerData.

In case anyone asks, my web service returns a string (serialized json).  I can't imagine the web service being an issue here seeing as though the request never even gets sent.

If I put a break point on the $.getJSON line, it never hits.

Thanks anyone for checking this out!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.  It was really dumb and just glaring at me.  I didn't have a table on the page with the id of "taskTable".  Before I took on the Ajax source part of the datatable I was loading the table from a different page.  I forgot to bring it forward.